# How do I get past "Could not queue the build because there were validation errors or warnings." while automating pipeline creation using az-cli

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines, azure-cli, azure-pipelines-yaml

I am trying to automate rsync pipeline creation using az-cli.
This is the command I am running from a local clone of my repository:

```
az pipelines create --name my_pipeline --yml-path azure-pipeline.yml --project my_project --repository my_repo --repository-type tfsgit
```

The pipeline is created but it is not able to queue it. Here are the details from the --debug switch. Am I missing something?
The expected output was to not only create the pipeline but also run it.

****WARNING: This command is in preview and under development. Reference and support levels: https://aka.ms/CLI_refstatus**

**WARNING: cli.azext_devops.dev.pipelines.pipeline_create: Successfully created a pipeline with Name: my_pipeline, Id: 2019.****

**DEBUG: msrest.exceptions: Could not queue the build because there were validation errors or warnings.**

DEBUG: cli.azext_devops.dev.common.exception_handler: **handling vsts service error**

DEBUG: cli.azure.cli.core.util: azure.cli.core.util.handle_exception is called with an exception:

DEBUG: cli.azure.cli.core.util: Traceback (most recent call last):

File "/usr/lib64/az/lib/python3.6/site-packages/azure/cli/core/commands/**init**.py", line 691, in _run_job

*result = cmd_copy(params)*

File "/usr/lib64/az/lib/python3.6/site-packages/azure/cli/core/commands/**init**.py", line 328, in **call**

*return self.handler(*args, **kwargs)*

File "/usr/lib64/az/lib/python3.6/site-packages/azure/cli/core/commands/command_operation.py", line 121, in handler

*return op(**command_args)*

File "/home/user/.azure/cliextensions/azure-devops/azext_devops/dev/pipelines/pipeline_create.py", line 155, in pipeline_create
project=project)

File "/home/user/.azure/cliextensions/azure-devops/azext_devops/devops_sdk/v5_1/build/build_client.py", line 337, in queue_build
content=content)

File "/home/user/.azure/cliextensions/azure-devops/azext_devops/devops_sdk/client.py", line 90, in _send

*response = self._send_request(request=request, headers=headers, content=content, media_type=media_type)*

File "/home/user/.azure/cliextensions/azure-devops/azext_devops/devops_sdk/client.py", line 54, in _send_request

*self._handle_error(request, response)*

File "/home/user/.azure/cliextensions/azure-devops/azext_devops/devops_sdk/client.py", line 233, in _handle_error

*raise AzureDevOpsServiceError(wrapped_exception)*

**azext_devops.devops_sdk.exceptions.AzureDevOpsServiceError: Could not queue the build because there were validation errors or warnings.**

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:
Traceback (most recent call last):

File "/usr/lib64/az/lib/python3.6/site-packages/knack/cli.py", line 231, in invoke

*cmd_result = self.invocation.execute(args)*

File "/usr/lib64/az/lib/python3.6/site-packages/azure/cli/core/commands/**init**.py", line 657, in execute

*raise ex*

File "/usr/lib64/az/lib/python3.6/site-packages/azure/cli/core/commands/**init**.py", line 720, in _run_jobs_serially

*results.append(self._run_job(expanded_arg, cmd_copy))*

File "/usr/lib64/az/lib/python3.6/site-packages/azure/cli/core/commands/**init**.py", line 712, in _run_job

*return cmd_copy.exception_handler(ex)*

File "/home/user/.azure/cliextensions/azure-devops/azext_devops/dev/common/exception_handler.py", line 18, in azure_devops_exception_handler

*raise CLIError(ex)*

**knack.util.CLIError: Could not queue the build because there were validation errors or warnings.**

**ERROR: cli.azure.cli.core.azclierror: Could not queue the build because there were validation errors or warnings.**

**ERROR: az_command_data_logger: Could not queue the build because there were validation errors or warnings.**

DEBUG: cli.knack.cli: Event: **Cli.PostExecute [<function AzCliLogging.deinit_cmd_metadata_logging at 0x7fe2e4a682f0>]**

INFO: az_command_data_logger: exit code: 1

INFO: cli.**main**: Command ran in 2.552 seconds (init: 0.200, invoke: 2.352)

INFO: telemetry.save: Save telemetry record of length 3257 in cache

WARNING: telemetry.check: Negative: The /home/user/.azure/telemetry.txt was modified at 2022-04-07 14:29:35.737231, which in less than 600.000000 s

***Additional information: I am setting the AZURE_DEVOPS_EXT_PAT env variable to authenticate and use az-cli commands.***

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error message says it all, it can't queue the build because there are errors in the YAML.

It created pipeline `2019`, you need to review the YAML and correct the validation errors before it'll run:

1. Open a browser and navigate to `https://dev.azure.com/<your-organization-name>/<your-project-name>/_build?definitionId=2019`
2. Click on the `Edit` button
3. In the elipsis context menu, select validate:

   [image]

The error message about the invalid syntax will be shown in a dialog box.

Alternatively, the Azure DevOps REST API exposes an endpoint to do the same:

- [preview pipeline](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/pipelines/preview/preview?view=azure-devops-rest-7.1)
- or [pipeline run](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/pipelines/runs/run-pipeline?view=azure-devops-rest-7.1) with the previewRun parameter specified in the request body

Comment: Thank you. I would never have guessed it was complaining about the YAML. For the build created using the az-cli command, I was not able to see the YAML in the webpage you posted. But there were 2 issues with it: 1. There was a syntax error in the yaml which we fixed. 2. The az-cli command also expects the yaml file to be a relative path from the local clone of the repo. I was instead using the absolute file path from the repo directory earlier which az-cli did not like (just az-cli things.......). Worked out well in the end. Thanks

Comment: Creating the pipeline is a one time activity. But because the yaml can version in multiple branches it is always going to be the source of your issues.